# Segfault with ESP outside the [stack] range in /proc/pid/maps?

Tags: assembly, x86, crash, stack-overflow, stack-memory

I am debugging a crash and i see following behaviour -

When i attach GDB to the process and do info registers, i see the following value for esp -

```
esp            0xfd2475d0       0xfd2475d0
```

Upon doing a disassembly of code where it is crashing, I see it's storing to memory pointed-to by the stack pointer -

```
81c886a:       c7 04 24 2c f9 8a 0c    movl   $0xc8af92c,(%esp)
```

And if i view maps file in `/proc/<PID>/maps`, I see stack address range as -

```
fff39000-fff59000 rwxp 7ffffffde000 00:00 0                              [stack]
```

Clearly, value of `ESP 0xfd2475d0` in GDB is not in sync with the stack address in maps file.

Can this be a reason for crash. I think it should be as i am getting SIGSEGV. Also, how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely option is over allocation.

```
 void foo() {    
     double too_big[6000000];    // this would be located at 0xfd...... 
     int a;                      // this would be located at 0xfff3f000 ... 
 }
```

Comment: Note that mainstream operating systems don't use segmentation, as such they don't catch accesses outside the designated stack area (only the usual memory protections apply). This is important if you use threading or sigaltstack, in which cases some other chunk of memory is used as stack.

Comment: Only the last part of this answer makes sense: too big an array on the stack, like a VLA or `alloca`, or just an unwise choice of a big constant size.  The OP's stack pointer got far outside the range of their stack mapping, so if it was just a stack overflow, it must have been in one huge stack frame.  Or yes, in a debug build, overwriting a saved EBP frame pointer could later get copied to ESP after a couple levels of returning when functions do `call foobar` (which saves/restores the current EBP to the stack) / ... / `mov esp, ebp` / `pop ebp` / `ret`